# Corona SDK: Rotate Image into the direction of shot

Tags: image, math, rotation, coronasdk, angle

I am currently working on a top view game with a hero, that can shoot bullets. This hero needs to rotate to the direction of the tab. The Image is facing north (top) as well as the image of the bullet, that would have also be rotated to the direction of the shot.

I do understand, that there is object.rotation as well as some math functions that would help, but I cant seem to get it figured out as the hero moves with each tab.

Thanks for any suggestions where to start!
fj

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got it to work by using more Google and Trail & Error:

```
hero.rotation = math.atan2((hero.y - y) , (hero.x - x)) * (180 / math.pi)
```

Works as long as the image is facing west/left.